# Inter VLAN on Netgear layer 2 switches

Tags: vlan, netgear

[image: Network Layout]

I have a basic setup as described in the (rather poor) image above. I have various VLANS;

- 1 Default
- 10 VOIP
- 20 Guest WIFI (Unifi)

I am looking at a way of doing Inter VLAN in this setup of layer 2 switches to allow certain cross VLAN communication.

Is this possible?

Comment: It's only possible if you have a Layer 3 device that can route traffic across the VLAN's.

Answer (score 3):

In short, no this is not possible.

To cross VLANs, you need a layer 3 device (L3 switch or a router). I'm going to assume that you have no control over the ISP CPE and say that you will need to acquire some additional equipment before making this setup work.